# How do I fix repeated error 0x8007f0f4 during install of KB2686509

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

(On XP, in the event log, this problem will show as "Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x8007f0f4: Security Update for Windows XP (KB2686509)." in the event log).

There's some help at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686509, but on my system there was no Faultykeyboard.log file to examine.

Comment: Please don't add tags for a specific update, these are usually much too localized.

Comment: @slhck - Since the question is about that exact update that the way in which it fails (a failure which is VERY specific to the update in question), I'd say it should be tagged with the update.

Comment: Given that there's only **one** question about KB2686509, it's much too localized. We don't have tags about other specific updates either — there's no gained value from it (no improved search, and there are no tag followers who are experts on "KB2686509"). The tag would have probably been automatically removed anyway. It's great that you posted this question and answer, a great resource, but it doesn't warrant its own tag. By the way, you should be able to even accept your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examination of the relevant registry keys

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts`

showed no file reference entries with files outside of System32. However, it did show that I had a "Scancode Map" installed in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.

By removing the Scancode Map key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` and then rebooting, I was able to install KB2686509 without further trouble, and I could reinstall my Scancode Map later.

Comment: For those unfamiliar: a Scancode Map in this location allows one to remap keyboard keys without loading further utilities. I use it to remap my caps lock key

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a VB Script](http://www.vivus.net/dl) to fix two problems while running Microsoft security update KB2686509

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map
```

and

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts
```

for those who are no registry freaks.

Here you can [download my little hotfix](http://www.vivus.net/dl) as ZIP-file.

What does it do? Nothing magic!

1. Makes a registry backup
2. deletes Scancode Map if exists
3. checks every keyentry in Keyboard Layouts against existing file in %SystemRoot%\System32

Answer (score 0):

I have a .reg file that disables the Caps lock key. I also have one that restores it back to the default. I saw a reference to re-mapped keys on another site so I tried resetting my caps lock hack back to the default and the Microsoft Security update KB2685609 installed successfully.

Problem solved.

---

Disable_caps_lock key UNDO remove_all_scancode_mappings.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]

"Scancode Map"=-
```

---

Disable_caps_lock key.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]

"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else might benefit from this: after running this ["fix-it" (216893)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150305132330/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/216893), this patch (KB2686509) was able to be successfully applied on my x86 Windows SP3 PC.

The advantage of trying this first is that you don't have to muck around in the registry or run some script.  I believe I ran the "fix-it" to "enable Windows key" (even though I don't think it was ever disabled), rebooted, patch applied, problem resolved (until next time...)